# Permissions Errors when running dev/build

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I get permissions errors when running dev/build in either the browser or the cli, depending on which way round I last "fixed" it.

Webserver is www-data
Deployment is ssh'd as "beanstalk" and that user is the only user to use the cli to do dev/build like so:

```
php vendor/silverstripe/framework/cli-script.php dev/build  flush=1
```

I can't change the user of the webserver or deployment service.

To untangle it when it gets mixed up so i can run it via the cli, I have to change the ownership to  beanstalk:www-data for these files:

```
/var/www/stage/public_html/.graphql-generated/
/var/www/stage/public_html/public/assets/.protected/.htaccess
/var/www/stage/public_html/public/assets/.htaccess
/var/www/stage/public_html/public/asset/404-error.html
/var/www/stage/public_html/public/asset/500-error.html
```

Then, to avoid further calamity, never ever ever run the dev/build?flush via the web browser, which is a peculiur restriction when using silverstripe, as its the go-to action to fix everything!

There are lots of other people over the years facing the same problems:

eg
https://forum.silverstripe.org/t/chmod-operation-not-permitted-vendor-league-flysystem/2020

There is some activity in the repo to fix this, but I can't find where the documentation is to use it, eg to set $default_server and how that helps.

https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-assets/issues/81

How can I set my permissions / configure silverstripe to allow www-data OR beanstalk to run the dev/build?

Answer (score 0):

If we have `sudo` permissions we can precede the `php` command with `sudo -u www-data`. This will run the `php` command as the `www-data` user.

```
sudo -u www-data php vendor/silverstripe/framework/cli-script.php dev/build  flush=1
```